# Why won't HTML5 video play in firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

I'm building a web page and want to add HTML video. It works fine in Chrome etc., but not in Firefox. I can hear the sound, but firefox is unable to show the picture, I get grey screen instead.

I've got Firefox 25.0.1

Here is my code:

```
            <figure id="video">
                <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                    <source src="vid/asd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="vid/asd.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                    Sorry Your browser cannot play HTML5 video.
                </video><br/>
                <img src="img/pic.jpg" alt="Pics"/>
                <figcaption>Some text here
                <br/>size: 6,95MB</figcaption>
            </figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a school project, just found out that the school's servers are not able to auto-get the MIME type under firefox. I had to add .htacces file

Answer (score 0):

`<video>` works for me in Firefox 25.0.1/Windows Vista. Maybe it's a problem with a movie? Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NanxS/).

Also, from the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) website:

> To avoid patent issues, support for MPEG 4, H.264, MP3 and AAC is not built directly into Firefox on desktop and mobile (Android and Firefox OS). Instead it relies on support from the OS or hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting well ask yourself what version of firefox your running and take a look at

http://www.videojs.com/

Hope that helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Well honestly I use firefox also but, Hmmm. Well remember to always to put .mp4 first! Because if not that creates some interesting bugs for ios...